# Experiencing tags on screen

Tags: css, tags, title, paragraph

I am calling title, body and few other things from database and using echo to display it on screen. Everything is working fine except body, where p tags are printed at start and end of body. My code is

```
          echo "<div class='db'>
          <h2 style='background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;'>".$row['title']."</h2>
          <p style='background-color:#ffffff'>" . 
  (strlen($row['body'])>500? 
      substr( $row['body'],0,500)."...<a href='blog.php?blogId=" . $row['blogs_id'] . "' style='font-size:13px;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;'>Read more</a>": 
      $row['body']).
  "</p>  
        <img src='$profilephoto_info' height='60' style='background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:20px;'> 
        By:<a href='$posted_by' style='background-color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;color:#626769;font-size:13px;'>$posted_by</a>
        <p style='background-color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;color:#626769;font-size:13px;''>".$row['bio']."</p>
        </div>";
```

No h2 tags appear for title nor for any other elements only body is showing p tags around it on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Format your code to know where things get missed up
consider heredoc
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
also loss the inline styles!

```
<?php
$title = $row['title'];
$shortBody = strlen($row['body']) >500 ? substr( $row['body'],0,500) : $row['body'];
$url = "blog.php?blogId=" . $row[' blogs_id '];
$bio = $row['bio '];

echo <<<dbElement
  <div class='db'>
      <h2 style='background-color:#FFF;color:#000;'>
          $title
        </h2>
      <p style='background-color:#FFF'>
          $shortBody ...
          <a href="$url" 
            style="font-size:13px;color:black;background-color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;">
              Read more
            </a>
      </p>
      <img src='$profilephoto_info' height='60' 
        style='background-color:#FFF;border-radius:20px;'> 
        By:
      <a href='$posted_by' 
        style='background-color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;color:#626769;font-size:13px;'>
          $posted_by
        </a>
      <p 
        style='background-color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;color:#626769;font-size:13px;'>
          $bio
      </p>
  </div>
dbElement;
?>
```

*make sure to not include my php opening and closing tags (`<?php and ?>`)

Comment: make sure to not include my php opening and closing tags (`<?php and ?>`)